# node.js installation and npm commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

[image: running npm -v command to check the version nut not working]
[image: complete error]

I want to download and start a project on react. But when I download the node.js and run any command it returns an error which I don't understand how to solve it.

I tried to reinstall it many times, but it gave me the same error.
So please, give me a solution. With your help, I will be able to start a project.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Copy and paste the text itself.

Comment: Also, please use punctuation. It is very difficult to understand your question when one has to first try to figure out where one sentence ends and the next one starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `npm init` first (if you haven't already)